# Need download version for i686

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386 on a Dell Dimension 4600.  I get a message - This kernel requires an i86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for you CPU.

This was the only 32 bit version I found to download.  How can I find the appropriate download version?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to boot with a 64-bit kernel.

Are you sure that you installed from an i386 version?  You shouldn't be getting this message from that.  Note that there is no i686 build of the whole OS, you need the i386 build.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Dimension 4600, and it has a Pentium 4 processor, which is a 32-bit (i686) CPU. I can run 32-bit (i386) Ubuntu family iso files live and I can install systems from them. The result described in the question is confusing. The

```
ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
```

file contains a system that should work as well as the more current

```
ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

file. It seems to me that the file names have been confused, and you have tried with 64-bit version.

But standard Ubuntu will be slow in that old computer. I would recommend an Ubuntu community family flavour with a lighter desktop environment,

- Lubuntu
- Ubuntu MATE
- Xubuntu.

You find the current versions and flavours via this link,

[releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

See also this link,

[How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Comment: @thomasrutter, I understand that you have much more experience of Ubuntu than I. But I have exactly the same kind of computer, Dell Dimension 4600 as described in the original question, and I am sharing my experience of that computer. It is possible to find i386 iso files via the link I provide, and it is really working much better with the lighter desktop environments of the community flavours. The Pentium 4 processor is not particularly good at running the current versions of standard Ubuntu with Unity.